# PostgreSQL How to do nested if statement before dropping a trigger

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm using PostgreSQL 15. In pgAdmin 4 version 6.19, I'm preparing a migration script in PostgreSQL. I have this command to drop a trigger tied to a table. But I want to check that:

1. The table exists first
2. The trigger exists second

I tried this command and many variations of it:

```
IF EXISTS dbo.cities then
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tr_city_check
    ON dbo.cities;
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 2: IF EXISTS dbo.cities then
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 2
```

What should I do to have query run successfully?

Comment: That's not even close to valid SQL though is it? Have a quick look at the official manuals on postgresql.org and perhaps refresh your memory. Also - how exactly could your trigger exist if the table it is attached to doesn't?

Comment: The content of this is PostgreSQL not regular SQL. I used AWS Schema Conversion Tool to convert that into Postgre. The tool is not 100% match. I think this is one of those cases that I'm manualy fixing. I guess the question is how to make this execute in Postgres with the double checks I aforementioned.

Comment: The only way this works is in a function or procedure.

Comment: it makes sense @AdrianKlaver why it won't work in a query.

Comment: Because `IF` is not a [SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-commands.html) command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I have is this query:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'cities') THEN
        DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tr_city_check
        ON dbo.cities;
    END IF;
END $$;
```